# GetDisplayMedia - Is there an event to listen when the shared application window is resized

Tags: javascript, webrtc, screensharing, get-display-media

Is there an event to listen, when the application that is shared via chrome getDisplayMedia is resized?

For example if a text editor application is shared and then resized while still being shared, then the video track also gets resized. But I dont find an event handler to listen to the size change. Is there an event to listen to?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is only way to monitor videoWidth/videoHeight using requestAnimationFrame etc.